# Opera 49.0 Can't Edit and Remove Default Search Engines (/ncr)

Tags: opera, search-engines, localization

I want to use "google.com/ncr" but I can't edit or remove default search engines in Opera Browser. There is no way to do that.

Redirection is pointless for me. I just want to search and get results about what I search. Localization results doesn't interest me.

Comment: Nobody knows about that :D

Comment: There is no any way to do that? Really?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the speed dial extension unfortunately, where you can create or edit the google link according to your desires. This Opera now is quite unfriendly directly. It intends to hide off the tweaking options whereas in the previous versions, users could have that freedom. 
To install the extension you will first need to go to : Menu > Extensions > Get extensions. Then do the search for Speed Dial in the "search for add-ons" box. There may be a few various kinds in the result. I think the FVD Speed Dial is still the easiest and best.

Comment: It's a shame for Opera. We are in 2017 and I need speed dial for modify to default search engine, weird.

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the URL [opera://settings/search](http://opera://settings/search). You'll see a drop-down there where you can choose a different default search engine. The list is limited to the default search engines listed under "Manage search engines". You can set a search engine you add as the default.